# Azure Portal - Can't set up deployment for deployment slot within web app

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azureportal

I want to set up deployment for a deployment slot within a web app. I followed the steps below:

1. Create doployment slot within web app
2. Access deployment slot
3. Click on Deployment Center
4. Select External
5. Select App Service Build Service
6. Enter repository URL: https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure
7. Enter branch name: master
8. Click Continue

This is the stage where I am stuck, as nothing happens beyond this point.

[image]

Checking the browser console, I discovered several errors, one related to Github:

[image]

Is this an issue for anyone else?